# WPF Create a kind of "variable" in xaml code in order to use in the rest of xaml code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wonder whether in `xaml` there is the possibility to create a "kind" of variable and then use it for the rest of xaml code. For example, suppose many controls share the same width so can I declare width once in xaml and then use it in all the xaml code?

Comment: There's no such thing as a variable in XAML. To get similar effects, you'll need to use bindings or in your example with width, using a style

Comment: @MattL. you refer to bindings within the same xaml? could you post a little example? for example suppose I want to define an integer value an use it in the whole xaml.

Comment: So say you want an element's width (an integer) to be the size of the window's width. For the element, you would say (let's say the Window is named "window") `Width="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=Width}"`. This will set the Width of the element to the value of the width of the window. And this works with plenty of other properties

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define your "variables" in resources, but I would prefer to use styles, to set Properties to same value:

```
xmlns:Sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"    

<Window.Resources>
    <Sys:Double x:Key="yourVar">30.0</Sys:Double>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox>            
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem FontSize="{Binding Source={StaticResource yourVar}}">1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```