# Set value in xaml using class field

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `DataGrid` as:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="4" Name="grvAllCry" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rank" Width="10*" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Rank}" Foreground="#46BF6E"></Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see, I set `Foreground` of row of `DataGrid` is "#46BF6E". But I have many `DataGrid` and I want to re-use this variables. Something like:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static string MyGreen = "#46BF6E";
    public static string MyRed = "#D14836";
    public static string MyBlue = "#428BCA";
}
```

Is there a way I can create a class like that and use it's variable in many different xaml files? For examples:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Rank}" Foreground="MyGreen"></Label>
```

I dont know how to call variable from .cs file while in xaml file, pls help me.

Comment: ResourceDictionary is your answer here. You would then use the variable as `StaticResource MyGreen`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Create a kind of "variable" in xaml code in order to use in the rest of xaml code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306885/wpf-create-a-kind-of-variable-in-xaml-code-in-order-to-use-in-the-rest-of-xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new `ResourceDictionary` where you define a `Brush` resource:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="myBrush" Color="#46BF6E"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If you want to be able to reference this resource throughout your entire application, you can then merge this resource dictionary into your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

...and reference the resource from any view using the `StaticResource` markup extension:

```
 <Label Content="{Binding Rank}" Foreground="{StaticResource myBrush}"></Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to referense `static` property or field (including `const` fields) using `{x:Static ...}` extension. For `Config` class it should be:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Rank}" Foreground="{x:Static myNameSpace:Config.MyGreen}"/>
```

xaml file should include namespace definition of Config class (`xmlsns:myNameSpace="...."`)

However, reusable elements are usually defined as Resources. Resources which are visible across the application are defined in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyGreen" Color="#46BF6E"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyRed" Color="#D14836"/>        
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBlue" Color="#428BCA"/> 
</Application.Resources>
```

such resources can be used from `StaticResource`/`DynamicResource` extension:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Rank}" Foreground="{StaticResource MyGreen}"/>
```